# how do i get words inside a String?

Tags: java, string, java-me, jakarta-ee

well i have this string

```
String mystring="anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{simpleType=anyType{restriction=anyType{maxLength=anyType{}; }; }; }; element=anyType{simpleType=anyType{restriction=anyType{maxLength=anyType{}; }; }; }; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{simpleType=anyType{restriction=anyType{maxLength=anyType{}; }; }; }; element=anyType{simpleType=anyType{restriction=anyType{maxLength=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; unique=anyType{selector=anyType{}; field=anyType{}; }; }; }; diffgram=anyType{DocumentElement=anyType{diagrama=anyType{iddiagrama=1; nombre=escuela; tipo=clase; descripcion=ejemplo de un diagrama de  clases de una escuela; }; diagrama=anyType{iddiagrama=3; nombre=xxx; tipo=clase; descripcion=jjjj; }; diagrama=anyType{iddiagrama=16; nombre=cas; tipo=Casos de uso; descripcion=us; }; diagrama=anyType{iddiagrama=21; nombre=escuela; tipo=Clase; descripcion=xxxxx; }; diagrama=anyType{iddiagrama=27; nombre=nombre del diagrama; tipo=Casos de uso; descripcion=aqui va la descripcion del diagrama; }; }; }; }
";
```

how do i get the value of iddiagrama, nombre, tipo, descripcion! note, there are more than 1 of everyone!
for example i would to get i dont know ! maybe in a array something so

```
String arrayid[] ={"1","3","16","21","27"};
String arraynombre[]={"escuela","xxx","cas","escuela","nombre del diagrama"};
```

and the same with tipo, and description

some idea?
*other thing
the lenght of characteres Change! because it is a query since a webservice!

i am trying it manuallity does someone has a example for to do it with a library?

Comment: Does the encoding of the data in your string follow any well known standard? If yes, there probably exist corresponding parser tools.

Comment: well this is a query since a web service which this is conected with database in sql server, then it does have the known standard, because i dont write the string, it is returned since web service, you know something about any tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to concatenate the strings in the array to form a string by running a for loop around each array. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes i have that idea but i dont know how to programming it, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your string contains data coded in JSON format.

You may use a JSON library like [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Then you don't have to parse the string manually.